# Filtering Data in DataGridViewer

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview, listbox, filtering

I've got a `DataGridViewer` in `Form B` and I've got a `listbox` in `Form A`. `Form A` always opens first and in the LoadEvent I've added this code:

```
ds = CreateDataset()
frm_Tasks.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Task")
LoadFromXMLfile("C:\Users\Beta4K\Documents\Tasks.FILE")
  For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
      ListBox1.Items.Add(dr("Task Name").ToString())
  Next
```

What this does is that it reads all the items in the Tasks.FILE and adds them to the DataGrdViewer in `Form B`. Now in `Form A` I've got a combobox with 3 items. Item 1, Item 2 Item 3. These are the items and in my `DataGridViewer`, when all the data is loaded, my 5th column has Item1 or Item 2 or Item 3. These are varied depending on what the user has chosen.

What I want to do is that once the items are loaded into the `listbox` in `Form A`, once the user selects Item 2 from the combobox, I want the listbox to only display all the items with Item 2 in the 5th column. Essentially filtering the `DataGridViewer` so that it will only show all items with `Item 2` in the 5th column.

If it's confusing let me know but till then it would be greatly appreciated if you could help me.

**Update**

```
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim dataset1 As New DataSet("Tasks")
Dim table1 As New DataTable("Task")
Private Sub frm_MainMenu_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ds = CreateDataset()
    frm_Tasks.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Task")
    LoadFromXMLfile("C:\Users\Beta4K\Documents\Tasks.FILE")
    For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
        ListBox1.Items.Add(dr("Task Name").ToString())
    Next

End Sub

Private Sub btn_Tasks_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Tasks.Click
    frm_Tasks.ShowDialog()
End Sub

Private Sub LoadFromXMLfile(filename As String)
    If System.IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
        Dim xmlSerializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(ds.GetType)
        Dim readStream As FileStream = New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open)
        ds = CType(xmlSerializer.Deserialize(readStream), DataSet)
        readStream.Close()
        frm_Tasks.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Task")
    Else
        MsgBox("file not found! add data and press save button first.", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "")
    End If
End Sub
Private Function CreateDataset() As DataSet
    table1.Columns.Add("Task ID")
    table1.Columns.Add("Task Name")
    table1.Columns.Add("Task Message")
    table1.Columns.Add("Task Date")
    table1.Columns.Add("Task Time")
    table1.Columns.Add("Task Group")
    dataset1.Tables.Add(table1)
    Return dataset1
End Function
```

**Update 2**
Brandon B helped me with my solution. It filters the rows fine now using:

```
 Dim dv As New DataView(ds.Tables("tableTask"))
    dv.RowFilter = "TaskGroup = 'Inbox'"
    frm_Tasks.DataGridView1.DataSource = dv.ToTable("Temp_table")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a to implement a dataview and a rowfilter.

```vb
private sub listbox_gridviewFilter(sender as listbox, e as eventargs) handles listbox1.selectedvaluechanged
    dim dv as new dataview(ds.Tables("Task"))        
    dv.RowFilter = "Task Name = '" & sender.selecteditem.tostring & "'"
    frm_Tasks.DataGridView1.DataSource = dv.totable("Temp_table")

end sub
```

In order for this to work, you will need to make ds form global or a public property also. I didn't have Visual Studio available, so you may need to check my syntax and correct any spelling errors, but I'm pretty sure I got it from memory.

---

### EDIT

There was so much going on, I had a hard time following it all. I have added alot of comments and I upgraded your error handling in the section that loads the XML. I'm not sure why you were trying to add tables to a seperate data set when it appered as though you XML reader was returning a Dataset for you. Take a look and see if this helps any. The only thing I am unsure about is having a space in the column name, "Task Name" when you go to use it in a row filter. it may need to be wrapped in single quotes, but I'm not sure.

```
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
Imports System.IO

Public Class Name_of_Form ' Need to change this to the name of the form

    Private ds As DataSet ' Made this private to the form, unless you need it across multiple forms then change Private to Public.
    ' Dim dataset1 As New DataSet("Tasks") ' you don't need this because you XML load is going to populate a DataSet for you
    ' Dim table1 As New DataTable("Task") ' You don't need this either because of the same
    Private Sub frm_MainMenu_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ' ds = CreateDataset() ' The dataset is is going to be returned in your XML loader
        LoadFromXMLfile("C:\Users\Beta4K\Documents\Tasks.FILE")
        frm_Tasks.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Task") ' Moved this below the XML loader, because you shouldn't set to something that isn't there yet...
        For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
            ListBox1.Items.Add(dr("Task Name").ToString())
        Next

    End Sub

    Private Sub btn_Tasks_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_Tasks.Click
        ' from your post it sounds like the user needs to have both forms open, so changing this to just show.
        ' frm_Tasks.ShowDialog()
        frm_Tasks.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub LoadFromXMLfile(filename As String)
        'adding some better error handling to see if your file isn't loading properly
        Try
            If System.IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
                Dim xmlSerializer As XmlSerializer = New XmlSerializer(ds.GetType)
                Dim readStream As FileStream = New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open)
                ds = CType(xmlSerializer.Deserialize(readStream), DataSet) ' this looks like it is returning a dataset. If I'm wrong, then everything I have here isn't going to work.
                readStream.Close()
                ' You don't need this line because I moved the same call in the Load method, I'm commenting it out.
                'frm_Tasks.DataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables("Task")
            Else
                Throw New Exception("file not found! add data and press save button first.")
            End If

            If IsNothing(ds) Then Throw New Exception("Nothing loaded into the DataSet")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "")
        End Try
    End Sub

    ' This is not really doing anything now. You said this is all your code, so since I commented out the call to it, I comenting this out too
    'Private Function CreateDataset() As DataSet
    '    table1.Columns.Add("Task ID")
    '    table1.Columns.Add("Task Name")
    '    table1.Columns.Add("Task Message")
    '    table1.Columns.Add("Task Date")
    '    table1.Columns.Add("Task Time")
    '    table1.Columns.Add("Task Group")
    '    dataset1.Tables.Add(table1)
    '    Return dataset1
    'End Function

    Private Sub listbox_gridviewFilter(sender As ListBox, e As EventArgs) Handles ListBox1.SelectedValueChanged
        Dim dv As New dataview(ds.Tables("Task"))
        dv.RowFilter = "Task Name = '" & sender.selecteditem.tostring & "'"
        frm_Tasks.DataGridView1.DataSource = dv.totable("Temp_table")

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I Updated the code for my purpose:
Dim ds As DataSet
Dim dataset1 As New DataSet("Tasks")
Dim table1 As New DataTable("Task")  
Dim dv As New DataView(ds.Tables("Task"))
dv.RowFilter = "'Task Group' = 'Inbox'"
frm_Tasks.DataGridView1.DataSource = dv.ToTable("Task")
But after running it it gives me a blank table. Any Idea why

Comment: @F4z    Have you filled the table Task with any data? Also, have you added the table that you just created to the dataset?

Comment: at the load event, it loads all the files to the table and it shows the data in the table.

Comment: @F4z   If the data is being loaded into the tables, then there is no need to be creating new datasets and new datatables. you are creating new tables that don't have anything in them and trying to work off that, which is why they are blank.

you need to post more surrounding code so I have a better idea of what is actually going on.

Comment: I'm not trying to create any new tables or anything, I'm just trying to filter the current data in my table, I have a column called "Task Group" and in that each row there will be a value e.g. Inbox, Important etc. I want it so that all rows with the "Important" tag to be filtered and showed only.

Comment: @F4z    The code that you added shows that you are creating a new dataset, then you are using that new data set and trying to get a Table named "Task", which you did create, however youvdidn't add to the dataset.  

Get rid of whatever you did. Add what I posted as a new method to the main form that opens. See if anything turns blue or red from intellisense and correct it if it does. If you already have data in the dataset/datatables then I don;t see why you are creating new ones. If you are getting errors about DS not being accessible, then you need to move ds to a broader scope in the form.

Comment: I've gotten rid of all the unwanted ones I just added, I've updated my post with all the code i currently have. Basically What I have is loading all the data to my table at the form load event. It loads all the data successfully to the table which I have in another form.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using `DataView`. Once you have to fill `DataTable`.

```
DataTable dtTable = new DataTable();
dtTable.Columns.Add("Column1");
dtTable.Columns.Add("Column2");
```

Then you have to create an object of `DataView` from created `DataTable`.

```
DataView dvSource = dtTable.DefaultView;
```

Now, you can assign that `DataView` object to your grid or any other listing control.

```
dataGridView.DataSource = dvSource;
```

Now you can filter your `DataGridView` using `DataView.RowFilter` property.

```
dvSource.RowFilter = 'Column1='" + cmbCombo.Text + "'";
```

Your grid will display only filtered items.